# iOS: Tracking User Movement 24/7

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager

I need to track when the user is traveling. For this I setup CLLocationManager like this:

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 200                       
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false                      
self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
self.locationManager.activityType = .other
```

So my app gets the location even if it is not running, saves the location in the DB and gets to background again. Later when the user is starting the app the travel is getting extracted from the new locations in the db.

This is working more or less with an energy consumption of ~15%. The position is determined with the help of cell towers and not by gps.

I realized that on some days the tracking is not working for some regions (train tracks). Do you have an idea why this happens? (Only iOS10 devices).

Do you see improvements to reach my goal? Is there anything else that can be used to determine a travel? (A travel is when you commute with more than 15 km/h and more than 15 min).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple activity type which can help you locate tracks, boats etc. Following is the apple doc on activity type:

```
public enum CLActivityType : Int {


    case other

    case automotiveNavigation // for automotive navigation

    case fitness // includes any pedestrian activities

    case otherNavigation // for other navigation cases (excluding pedestrian navigation), e.g. navigation for boats, trains, or planes
}
```

You can use `self.locationManager.activityType = .otherNavigation`

Answer (score 0):

With `iOS 12` you can also monitor position using the new activity type:

> "Use this activity type if the expected user activity is well above
>   ground level."

```
CLActivityType.airborne
```

As Apple suggest in the reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clactivitytype/airborne